# Dynamic Hashes: adding more to a hash within a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

Ruby beginner. Added a hash within a hash, but was unable to "add" more keys and values to the hash, without writing over the first key and value in the new hash. Sample code:

```
contacts = {
    "Jason" => {
      "phone" => 833,
      "twitter" => "sliceyboi",
      "email" => "crystal@lake"
    },
    "Freddy" => {
      "phone" => 666,
      "tiktok" => "asdf",
      "instagram" => "def",
      "email" => "in.your@dreams"
    }
  }

while true
puts contacts

new_key_and_value = {}

puts "add name"

name_key = gets.chomp

puts "add media:"
new_key = gets.chomp
 
puts "add #{new_key} info:"
new_value = gets.chomp

new_key_and_value[new_key] = new_value

contacts[name_key] = new_key_and_value
end
```

I can add "Chucky" "email: doll@toys". But if I go through again, for any of the names for Chucky or any of them, I was hoping to add more media, not overwrite. I know it has something to do with the new hash created.

So for example what it does:

```
add name

>Chucky
add media:
>email
add email info:
> doll@toys

{"Jason"=> 
     { "phone"=>833, 
     "twitter"=>"sliceyboi", 
     "email"=>"crystal@lake"},
 
"Freddy"=>
      {"phone" => 666,
      "tiktok" => "asdf",
      "instagram" => "def",
      "email" => "in.your@dreams"}, 

"Chucky"=>
     {"email"=>"doll@toys"}
    }

add name
>Chucky
add media:
>tiktok
add tiktok info:
>chplay

{"Jason"=> 
     { "phone"=>833, 
     "twitter"=>"sliceyboi", 
     "email"=>"crystal@lake"},
 
"Freddy"=>
      {"phone" => 666,
      "tiktok" => "asdf",
      "instagram" => "def",
      "email" => "in.your@dreams"}, 

"Chucky"=>
     {"tiktok"=>"chplay"}
    }
```

looking for:

```
{"Jason"=> 
     { "phone"=>833, 
     "twitter"=>"sliceyboi", 
     "email"=>"crystal@lake"},
 
"Freddy"=>
      {"phone" => 666,
      "tiktok" => "asdf",
      "instagram" => "def",
      "email" => "in.your@dreams"}, 

"Chucky"=>
     {"email"=>"doll@toys",
     "tiktok"=>"chplay",
}
    }
```

So that it is adding onto the end of the Chucky hash

Comment: I suggest that whenever you give an example you show the expected result (as a Ruby object). That tends to be helpful for readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know it has something to do with the new hash created.

You're correct. All you need to do is remove `new_key_and_value = {}` and instead where you write

```rb
new_key_and_value[new_key] = new_value

contacts[name_key] = new_key_and_value
```

write

```rb
# if contact doesn't exist create it.
if not contacts.key?(name_key) then contacts[name_key] = {} end

contacts[name_key][new_key] = new_value
```

---

Alternatively, you could have replaced `new_key_and_value = {}` with `new_key_and_value = contacts.key?(name_key) ? contacts[name_key] : {}`, but if that contact is large you're making a copy in memory for no reason, and it's less descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following methods.

```
def add_contact(contacts)
  name = seek("What is name to add?")
  h = {}
  loop do
    key, val = add_media
    break if key == ''
    h[key] = val
  end
  contacts[name] = h
  contacts 
end

def add_media
  key = seek("Add media (enter empty string when finished")
  return key if key.empty?
  [key, seek("Add #{key} information")]
end

def seek(msg)
  print "#{msg}: "
  gets.chomp
end
```

---

If the dialogue were:

```
add_contact contacts
What is name to add?: Chucky
Add media (enter empty string when finished: email
Add email information: doll@toys
Add media (enter empty string when finished: tiktok
Add tiktok information: chplay
Add media (enter empty string when finished:
```

the method would return:

```
#=> { "Jason"=>{
#       "phone"=>833,
#       "twitter"=>"sliceyboi",
#       "email"=>"crystal@lake"
#     },
#     "Freddy"=>{
#       "phone"=>666,
#       "tiktok"=>"asdf",
#       "instagram"=>"def",
#       "email"=>"in.your@dreams"
#     },
#     "Chucky"=>{
#       "email"=>"doll@toys",
#       "tiktok"=>"chplay"
#     }
#   }
```

The last line of `add_contact` is optional. `contacts` will be modified as desired if it is not present. I've included it so that one could write something like

```
add_contact(contacts).each { |k,v| .... }
```

rather than

```
add_contact(contacts)
contacts.each { |k,v| .... }
```

should that be desired.